# Preventing user to click other cell in kendo grid

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

I have kendo child grid. It's having some row. Each row having some cells. If i change the value of a cell other than first row,i have to get the corresponding first row cell value and do some validation. See the attached image

[image]

Code

```
 var $container = $(container),
        tdIndex = $container.index(),
        $correspondingCell = $container.closest("tbody").find("tr:first td:eq(" + tdIndex + ")");
            $('<input  maxlength="9" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo($container)
                .kendoNumericTextBox({
                    format: "0.####",
                    decimals: 0,
                    min: 0,
                    spinners: false,
                    change: function (e) {
                        //debugger;
                        CalculateFormatWeeks(options.model);
                        var uid = options.model.uid;
                        var cellinx = $('#kenTitleFormatsGrid .k-edit-cell')[0].cellIndex;
                        var row = $("#kenTitleFormatsGrid tbody").find("[data-uid='" + uid + "']");
                        var cell = row.children().eq(cellinx);
                        cell.css("font-style", "normal");
                        console.log("From Cell", $correspondingCell.text());
                        if (Number($correspondingCell.text()) == 0) {
                            alert("There is no daily GBO exists to enter the format gross. Please add the daily GBO data before proceeding");
                        }
                    }                        
                }).off("keydown");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for the Grid's save event and use the grid.editCell() method when required, i.e:

```
save: function (e) {
    var $container = $(e.container),
        tdIndex = $container.index(),
        $correspondingCell = $container.closest("tbody").find("tr:first td:eq(" + tdIndex + ")");

    if (Number($correspondingCell.text()) == 0) {
        alert("There is no daily GBO exists to enter the format gross. Please add the daily GBO data before proceeding");
        e.sender.editCell($container);
    }
  }
```

Demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/EDeFO

Comment: I have to write this condition in change event of cell, if i write in save event for me it's firing more than one time because on change of this cell value i am automatically changing the week and weekend columns values, so its firing more times

Comment: Then add a check against e.values and an if-statement to only process when and what you want.  The save event fires on every cell so you have to add the logic to do the appropriate processing on the cells you want and to do nothing on cells you don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

try it 
script level

```
function CloseEditable(e) {    
        this.closeCell();
```

}

view level

Events(events => events.Edit("CloseEditable")

if you want close particular cell then get cellIndex of cell

Comment: I don't think he wants to just not edit the cell he clicked on...he wants to keep the editor on the cell he is leaving.